# Setting value of textview via handler

Tags: android

I have a handler inside oncreate of an activity.  It receives a value from `handler.sendEmptyMessage`.

handleMessage is fired and it reaches till the line where I try to update the textview as shown below:

```
mImageCountText.setText("" + mCountText);
```

But the text of textview never gets changed. What am I missing here?

Is there anything obvious that causes this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Handler code

```
 Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            final int what = msg.what;
            if (what == Constants.HANDLER_APP_UPDATE) {
                if (!UserHelper.isAppBuildVerionSameAsUpdate(HomeActivity.this)) {
                    updateNotificationAlert();
                    showAppUpdatePopUp();
                }
            } else if (what == Constants.HANDLER_COLLECTION_UPDATE) {
                //TODO: Refresh collection
            } else {
                mCountText = what;
                if (!Utils.isTablet()) {
                    if (mCountText == 0) {
                        mImageCountText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {

                        mImageCountText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageCountText.setText("" + mCountText); // this does not work
                    }
                } else {

                    if (mCountText == 0) {
                        mCollectionsFragment.refreshAfterUpload();
                        mCountTextForUplaod.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        mCollectionsFragment.refreshAfterUpload();
                        mCountTextForUplaod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mCountTextForUplaod.setText("" + mCountText);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Onreceive from where value is sent

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER)) {
                    boolean broadcastStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_DATA_STATUS, false);
                    String broadcastStatusMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_DATA_STATUS_MESAGE);
                    if (broadcastStatus) {
                        mCountText = PreferenceHelper.getFromPreference(context, Constants.RECENT_IMAGES_COUNT, 0);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(PreferenceHelper.getFromPreference(context, Constants.RECENT_IMAGES_COUNT, 0));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_APP_UPDATE)) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.HANDLER_APP_UPDATE);
                    } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_COLLECTION_UPDATE)) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.HANDLER_COLLECTION_UPDATE);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
```

Comment: Please post the handler code, how you post the message and how you handle it.

Comment: I have posted as requested.

Comment: Your code is too complex, you don't need a thread in onReceive. You are using the "what" both to identify the message, and to pass the count. That is wrong, the count could be one of your values APP_UPDATE or COLLECTION_UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complex. You don't need the handler and definitively not the thread. Thy it like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER)) {
        boolean broadcastStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_DATA_STATUS, false);
        String broadcastStatusMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_DATA_STATUS_MESAGE);
        if (broadcastStatus) {
            mCountText = PreferenceHelper.getFromPreference(context, Constants.RECENT_IMAGES_COUNT, 0);
            if (mCountText == 0) {
                mCollectionsFragment.refreshAfterUpload();
                mCountTextForUplaod.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mCollectionsFragment.refreshAfterUpload();
                mCountTextForUplaod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCountTextForUplaod.setText("" + mCountText);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_APP_UPDATE)) {
            if (!UserHelper.isAppBuildVerionSameAsUpdate(HomeActivity.this)) {
                updateNotificationAlert();
                showAppUpdatePopUp();
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_COLLECTION_UPDATE)) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```